# Does Seam produce an endless loop?

Tags: java, jboss, seam, eclipselink

I followed [this  tutorial](http://www.open-tutorial.com/2011/01/26/seam-persistence-provider-hibernate-eclipselink/) to configure an application (generated by seam-gen) to use eclipselink instead of hibernate.

After that the following messages appear in an endless loop after the first request from a browser ocurred.
What could cause this behaviour?

I was not able to find the source file which contains the string "Added Library from" to examine the issue with a debugger, any pointers are appreciated.

```
INFO  [Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel) [4.3.0.GA_CP06 (build: SVNTag=JBPAPP_4_3_0_GA_CP06 date=200907141446)] Started in 26s:623ms
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-ui.jar!/META-INF/s.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-ui.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-fn.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/ajax4jsf.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/jsp.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/richfaces.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-ui.jar!/META-INF/s.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-ui.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-fn.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/ajax4jsf.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/jsp.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/richfaces.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-ui.jar!/META-INF/s.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-html.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jsf-ui.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-core.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jsf-facelets.jar!/META-INF/jstl-fn.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/a4j.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/ajax4jsf.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/jsp.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/rich.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-ui.jar!/META-INF/richfaces.taglib.xml
INFO  [compiler] Added Library from: jar:file:/C:/dev/jboss-4.3.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app.ear/app.war/WEB-INF/lib/jboss-seam-ui.jar!/META-INF/s.taglib.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you alter an xml file as part of your changes? Eclipse stores a backup of changed configuration files as a *.jsfdia file, or something similar. These files can cause the application to enlessly deploy & redeploy. If these files exist, remove them from the deployed app folder and the problem will go away.

Comment: thanks for your reply, it happens during runtime, it is not an issue with continous deployment.