# What is the faces-config.xml.jsfdia file for?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf

Some research I did revealed that the `faces-config.xml.jsfdia` file is generated by eclipse as some kind of diff for the `faces-config.xml` [(source)](https://community.jboss.org/thread/191187), that it sometimes causes deployment issues on older JBoss servers [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992322/does-seam-produce-an-endless-loop).

And the first couple hundreds of google results also demonstrated that many project actually keep their `faces-config.xml.jsfdia` under version control.

Is it oversight? Is the file actually good for something? Even without having the `faces-config.xml` under version control, eclipse has a local history which it could use to restore the config, so why would it keep a separate diff of the settings? There isn't even a (would be quite useless anyway) "revert config" option, so what's the point?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `faces-config.xml.jsfdia` file is the Eclipse-specific file which contains the diagram representation of `faces-config.xml`.  If you open the `faces-config.xml` file and switch to *Diagram* tab (there are three tabs at left bottom of the editor view; *Diagram*, *Tree* and *Source*), then this file will be auto-created if not present. It remembers all diagram drawings which of course can't be remembered in `faces-config.xml` file itself.

You need to add this file to the ignore list of your version control program. E.g. the `.hgignore` file in project root in case of [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/):

```
syntax: regexp
\.jsfdia$
```

Or the `.gitignore` file in case of [git](https://git-scm.com/):

```
*.jsfdia
```

Comment: Great as always. Thank you, BalusC